# CodeIgniter inserting data to database with quotes in string

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, codeigniter-3

data is look like

```
$data = array
(
'question' => 'How to say “something” in'
'answer_one' => '1. Some Answer'
...
'correct_answer' => 1
);
```

I use

```
$this->db->insert('questions',$data);
```

When i run

```
$this->db->last_query()
```

I get:

```
INSERT INTO `questions` (`question`, `answer_one`, ... , `correct_answer`) VALUES ('How to say “Something”  in', '1. Some Answer', ... ,'1')
```

and Data saved as

How to say ?Something?  in

And the

```
$data = array
(
'question' => 'My Name is…'
'answer_one' => '1. Some Answer'
...
'correct_answer' => 1
);
```

is run as

```
INSERT INTO `questions` (`question`, `answer_one`, ... , `correct_answer`) VALUES ('My Name is…', '1. Name', ... , '1')
```

Is inserted as

"My Name is?"

```
$data = array
(
'question' => 'What's your name?'
'answer_one' => '1. Some Answer'
...
'correct_answer' => 1
);
```

is inserted as

What?s your name?

And Question table is like

```
CREATE TABLE `questions` (
 `question_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `question` varchar(200),
 `answer_one` varchar(80),
 ...
 `correct_answer` int(2),
 `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (`question_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: is it just some funky double quotes you cut and paste off the web?

Comment: I get data from excel file uploaded by the client

Comment: perhaps [edit] the question and show more info of the section of code or the flow that could intercept this and tweak it. Perhaps lose a tag and add `Excel`

Comment: @Drew there is nothing to do with excel actually i read the string correctly. Problem is in save it to mysql

Comment: can you show a schema of table `questions` and the actual raw string that is performed without ellipses I am confused how to help. Perhaps the issue is just getting the correct unicode value for the fancy quotes, and using the str_replace in Abdulla's answer

Comment: @drew problem occurs when "..." and " ' " also when there.

Comment: ok, well if I had your schema from the output of `show create table questions` maybe I could recreate it from raw. Who knows, maybe it is some martian character set that does that. oh, I see it now, I see said the blind man, sorry

Comment: ok I see what you see. Just a second

Answer (score 1):

Use [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

```
$data = array
(
    'question' => htmlentities('How to say “something” in'),
    'answer_one' => '1. Some Answer'
    ...
    'correct_answer' => 1
);
```

Or

Use [`str_replace()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

```
$value = 'How to say “something” in';
$data = array
(
    'question' => str_replace('"', '', $value);,
    'answer_one' => '1. Some Answer'
     
     'correct_answer' => 1
);
```

Comment: didn't worked since " “ " and " ”  " are not quotes :(

Answer (score 1):

It is an issue with the client characterset. When, based on what I had before in mysql command line client (when in client), and I run `status;`, I get, among other things:

### mysql> status;

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.24, for Win64 (x86_64)

Connection id:          88
Server version:         5.6.24-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Protocol version:       10
Connection:             localhost via TCP/IP
Server characterset:    utf8
Db     characterset:    utf8
Client characterset:    cp850
Conn.  characterset:    cp850
```

Then:

```
mysql> use so_gibberish;
Database changed
mysql> select * from questions;
+-------------+----------------------------+----------------+----------------+---------------------+
| question_id | question                   | answer_one     | correct_answer | created_at          |
+-------------+----------------------------+----------------+----------------+---------------------+
|           1 | How to say ?Something?  in | 1. Some Answer |              1 | 2015-11-01 21:06:23 |
+-------------+----------------------------+----------------+----------------+---------------------+
```

Even creating another database like:

```
CREATE DATABASE newdb CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
use newdb;

CREATE TABLE `questions` (
 `question_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `question` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin, -- utf8_unicode_ci,
 `answer_one` varchar(80),
 `correct_answer` int(2),
 `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (`question_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE questions CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
```

Did not make a difference.

It wasn't until I ran

```
mysql> charset utf8;
Charset changed
mysql> select * from questions;
+-------------+--------------------------------+----------------+----------------+---------------------+
| question_id | question                       | answer_one     | correct_answer | created_at          |
+-------------+--------------------------------+----------------+----------------+---------------------+
|           1 | How to say "Something"  in     | 1. Some Answer |              1 | 2015-11-01 21:06:23 |
+-------------+--------------------------------+----------------+----------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

was it good. Note when I run `status;` now I get

```
Server characterset:    utf8
Db     characterset:    utf8
Client characterset:    utf8
Conn.  characterset:    utf8
```

Refer to the mysql manual page entitled [Connection Character Sets and Collations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html)

### Connection Lifetime

That worked fine, til I started the client up fresh again. So there are INI file or CONF file settings

### Mysql Workbench

I never had an issue over there at all, even from the beginning. So it has a different `client characterset`

### Your World

Whatever that connection is, it needs to get the `client characterset` over to UTF8

Comment: When i chage to UTF-8 

data saved only

"How to say",  
"My Name is", "What"

Comment: what technically is the client app? Is it mysql command line utility, a PHP connection? Show the code in detail, maybe in a `pastie.org` page if you need to. Then describe what other angle (what code, what utility) you went in to see the data wrong. There are too many permutations to make assumptions here

Comment: it is a codeigniter application. I'm using active record and query builder of it.

Comment: $this->db->insert('questions',$data);